# Simulator doesn't handle spaces well on Windows 10

Tags: codenameone

I've had some trouble loading skins for the simulator. Turns out it was because there's a space in my Windows user name, and the function looking for skins converted the space to "%20". I've solved the problem for now with a symlink to the directory, but it's still a bug.

Comment: And? This isn't a bug reporting site.

Comment: When you say trouble loading the skins can you elaborate a bit? In the more menu? Download? Update framework? Do you have a stack trace or other reference?

Comment: I download skins  via the "Skins|More..." menu item, but the downloaded skins never appear in the "Skins" menu. Procmon reveals that the application searches for skins in the folder "C:\Users\John%20Smith\.codenameone\" instead of "C:\Users\John Smith\.codenameone\".